# What algorithm or data structures support exact searches with part or all of the query in quotes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose you search on Google with a query like this:

```
"term1 term2" term3 term4
```

For this query Google should return only results that include literally exactly term1 term2 and results that are about term3 and term4.

My question is what datastructures or algorithms support this functionality?  It seems to me like asking if a document contains an exact string is an O(N) operation and N is way too large for Google to be doing this.  How could Google filter documents that have an exact match to quoted queries quickly?

Put another way, not specific to Google, how would you go about implementing the exact string match on potentially massive numbers of documents.

Comment: they might use regex as well. In addition, we can assume the page is already indexed before it shows up on the google search results which means that it just needs to do a text analysis (still very complex)

Comment: I'd start with an index of words. Each word would map to a list. Each entry in the list would have a document identifier, and information about the location of the word in the document. So given the search request `"term1 term2"`, retrieve the lists for term1 and term2, and then find all documents that have those terms in close proximity.

Comment: This is not a full answer, but the original Google paper from 1998, [The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine](https://research.google/pubs/pub334/), goes into enough detail about the algorithms and data structures for indexing, inverted indexing, and scaling that you could even reconstruct their work. Documents are processed and indexed before queries are made. Of course, this is very far from the current search algorithms, but the system in that paper includes what is essentially a huge sorted dictionary mapping words to documents.